# Genymotion is stuck in emergency dial mode

Tags: genymotion

I have seen hints online about getting physical phones unstuck from emergency dial mode (e.g. remove the battery to reset the device), but I can't figure out how to apply those hints to the Emulator

Thanks!

[image: Emergency Dialer Mode]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer turned out to be pretty obvious. This wasn't emergency dial mode, it was the enter a pin screen. So once I entered my pin, the screen went away, and I was able to use the device. :D